# Php & XML - Get item by id

Tags: php, xml, extract

I've got an XML file like this:

```
<item id="55">
<title>Title</title>
...
</item>
```

and a php file which puts the XML data on an array...

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

But how can I only get **only one item** on based on the id attribute?

I tried this but didn't work...

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsById('55') as $node) {
```

Comment: [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

use `xpath` to select nodes with specific attributes only. In my example, I use `simplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$node = $xml->xpath("//item[@id='55']")[0];

echo $node->title;
```